# Pandas: categorical column and insertion of rows for every category

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I seem unable to achieve inserting rows with missing values, while having one column as Categorical.

Assume the following dataframe df, where column B is categorical and categories should appear in the order of 'd', 'b', 'c', 'a'.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'A':['i', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'k'], \
                  'B':pd.Categorical(['d', 'c', 'b','b', 'a'], \
                                     categories= ['d', 'b', 'c', 'a'], \
                                     ordered=True), \
                  'C':[1, 0, 3 ,2, np.nan]})
```

I need to convert df into the following format:

```
   A  B    C
 0  i  d  1.0
 1  i  b  0.0
 2  i  c  3.0
 3  i  a  NaN
 4  j  d  NaN
 5  j  b  2.0
 6  j  c  NaN
 7  j  a  NaN
 8  k  d  NaN
 9  k  b  NaN
10  k  c  NaN
11  k  a  NaN
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could set the dataframe index to column `B`, this way we can use the `reindex` later on to fill the missing categorical values for each group. Use `groupby` column `A` and select the column `C`, then apply the `reindex` function as mention before, using now the desired category sequence. Afterwards, use `reset_index` to insert the indices (`A` and `B`) back into dataframe columns.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['i', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'k'], \
                  'B':pd.Categorical(['d', 'c', 'b','b', 'a'], \
                                     categories= ['d', 'b', 'c', 'a'], \
                                     ordered=True), \
                  'C':[1, 0, 3 ,2, np.nan]})
print(df)

df = df.set_index('B')
df = df.groupby('A')['C']\
        .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']))\
        .reset_index()

df.B = pd.Categorical(df.B)
print(df)
```

Output from *df*

```
    A  B    C
0   i  d  1.0
1   i  b  3.0
2   i  c  0.0
3   i  a  NaN
4   j  d  NaN
5   j  b  2.0
6   j  c  NaN
7   j  a  NaN
8   k  d  NaN
9   k  b  NaN
10  k  c  NaN
11  k  a  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will go back to my original dataset to try this out!