# Dataframe saved as csv disappears the columns with nan values (python). Any solution?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a df where some columns host totally nan values and when I save the df as csv, these columns do not exist.

I have tried some solutions I found online, such as convert every column `astype('object')` or `astype('int')` or to `.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True)''' or to` .replace(np.nan, 'empty', regex=True)''' et cetera but none worked.

To give you some background info, the df accrued in the following way:

```
 In[]: dataset
Out[]:
       B3A    T3A     C2
 1    67.4    NaN    1.9
 2    25.5    NaN    NaN
 3     NaN    1.7   11.4
 4     NaN    4.0    NaN
 5     NaN   11.5   27.1

 In[]: df = dataset.reindex(columns=['B2', 'C1', 'T3A', 'C2', 'B3A'])
 In[]: df
Out[]:
   B2  C1   T3A    C2   B3A
1 NaN NaN   NaN   1.9  67.4
2 NaN NaN   NaN   NaN  25.5
3 NaN NaN   1.7  11.4   NaN
4 NaN NaN   4.0   NaN   NaN
5 NaN NaN  11.5  27.1   NaN
```

So when I do something like `df.to_csv('df.csv')` the column B2 and C1 just do not appear.

Is there a way to have all the nan columns in the csv? I would not be able to insert them manually as the previous is a small example and of course there is a point for the columns to follow the specific order.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df.to_csv('df.csv') the column B2 and C1 just do not appear.` - Do you think there are no columns names? Or empty strings separated by comma what is expected ouput?

Comment: Or need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36405994/save-pandas-dataframe-but-conserving-na-values) - `df.to_csv('df.csv', na_rep='NaN')` ?

Comment: Hmmm... true! If I do ```df.columns``` the nan columns do not appear... I get something like: ```CategoricalIndex(['T3', 'C2', 'B3A'], ordered=True, name='ques', dtype='category')```, which is true because this dataset is the output of ```pivot()``` to another dataset with the ```['B2', 'C1', 'T3A', 'C2', 'B3A']``` being categorical. Is there a way to actually fix this? Had tried the ```na_rep='NaN'``` but had not worked.

Comment: For me working your solution well, but maybe need `df = dataset.reindex(columns=pd.CategoricalIndex(['B2', 'C1', 'T3A', 'C2', 'B3A'], ordered=True))`

Comment: @jezrael you are such a SAVIOUR!!!

THANK YOU so much!!!

Comment: @Newbielp , jezrael  is champ +1!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CategoricalIndex` for [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), but in some oldier/ another pandas version also working your solution:

```
new = pd.CategoricalIndex(['B2', 'C1', 'T3A', 'C2', 'B3A'], ordered=True)
df = dataset.reindex(columns=new)
```

Comment: Many Thanks!! ...and it also partially solves another question I had (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135314/pandas-categorical-column-and-insertion-of-rows-for-every-category). With your solution, I suspect I can melt the columns and have nans at the rows...